# The ghost of layout in viewpager and fragment

Tags: android

I use the viewpager and fragment, the adapter is FragmentStatePagerAdapter, fragment's layout i use is SwipeRefreshLayout(22.0.0)+ListView, the ViewPager's setOffScreenPageLimit is 1, Just think i click in all the fragment, current is fragment 1 tap the refresh then click to fragment 3  then go back! the ghost is come up! [image]

Comment: I solve it in onDestroyView() use mSwipeRefreshLayout.removeAllViews()

Comment: Works nicely! Please post as answer and accept it.

Comment: cannot post my own answer!