# RecyclerView on top of another RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

Has anyone ever seen this weird behaviour where there is a RecyclerView on top of another RecyclerView? Any clues are appreciated!

**The setup:**

- 3 fragments inside a viewpager, each holding separate RecyclerView's
- each fragment is set to load more items into the RecyclerView when scrolled to the bottom

**To reproduce the problem:**

If I'm on the first fragment for example and then scroll down such that it starts loading the next page, then immediately switch to the third fragment in the viewpager and back again before it finishes loading, then I see the previous items that were on the screen with the progress bar, and the real list behind it which scrolls and accepts clicks. I can't interact with the previous items which seem like they are burnt onto the screen somehow. So weird. I can only see the real list through the margin gaps in between items when I scroll. Hopefully my explanation makes sense! If not I'm happy to answer questions or clarify further.

**I don't have this problem on a configuration change such as rotation**, only when switching from one fragment and back using the ViewPager, and only during a load. Happens on both single (phone) and dual pane (tablet) versions. Is this an issue with the ViewPager maybe? If it's not happening on rotation does this necessarily mean it's not a problem with the way the fragments save state or restore themselves? As usual it's probably something simple but I'm currently lost. Hopefully someone out there has seen this or knows what it might be.

## **Update:**

For anyone interested, this [The ghost of layout in viewpager and fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673214/the-ghost-of-layout-in-viewpager-and-fragment) post solves the problem. I'm not sure if there's another way apart from increasing the number of active pages in the ViewPager. I didn't see this post when I did my search, it was mentioned by someone else. I'm waiting for them to answer so I can give them the points. However, even though this works, I'm still not quite sure why the problem is happening in the first place. If someone can answer that question then maybe I would accept that as the answer instead. The problem only occurs when I've sent a request to Volley to download more content and set the progressbar to active. During onPause I cancel these downloads and set the progressbar to inactive. What then is the difference to the layout that causes it to get frozen on the screen when it otherwise wouldn't if I didn't request any downloads? It still seems very strange. I feel like there's something I'm missing here. Also, by removing all the views I now have this small bug (if you want to nitpick) where if I scroll down to get more content on the first tab and then click on the third tab before it finishes downloading, then rotate the screen, then go back to the first tab, the previous items don't appear back on the screen until it has loaded the new content; the screen is just black with the progressbar. Without the rotation I would be able to see the previous items in the list while it's loading the new ones. I hope all that makes sense!

I've also put the source code up here https://github.com/mvescovo/moviehotness if you happen to be curious about this problem and want to try it out for yourself. Just comment out `mLayoutManager.removeAllViews();` from ViewMoviesFragment.java which at the time of writing is line 261.